# VB.Net Crystal Report datasource is a .Net Object with some NULL properties

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, datasource

I am trying to create a Crystal Report with my custom object as the datasource.
It all works great unless some of the object's properties have null values. In that case, I get the error:

```
Error number: 5
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

(Not much help!)

Here's a copy of my code showing one CrystalReportViewer getting correctly populated by an object with no null values and another CrystalReportViewer giving the error with an object with a null value.

Thanks for any help/advice!

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        Try

            Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument

            'Verify the path to the Crystal Report's .RPT file:
            Dim strReportPath As String = CurDir() & "\..\..\" & "rpt_report.rpt"
            If Not IO.File.Exists(strReportPath) Then
                Throw (New Exception("Unable to locate report file:" & vbCrLf & strReportPath))
            End If

            cryRpt.Load(strReportPath)

            Dim reportArray1(0) As cls_object
            reportArray1(0) = New cls_object()
            reportArray1(0).iNumber = 99
            reportArray1(0).strString = "Hello"
            cryRpt.SetDataSource(reportArray1)

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()



            Dim reportArray2(0) As cls_object
            reportArray2(0) = New cls_object()
            'reportArray1(0).iNumber = 99 'this is commented out. this line is the only difference
            reportArray1(0).strString = "Hello"
            cryRpt.SetDataSource(reportArray2)

            CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = cryRpt
            CrystalReportViewer2.Refresh()



        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Err.Source)
        End Try


    End Sub
End Class

Public Class cls_object

    Protected _iNumber As Integer?
    Protected _strString As String

    Public Property iNumber() As Integer
        Get
            Return _iNumber
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _iNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property strString() As String
        Get
            Return _strString
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _strString = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not using a DBNull, You are using the `Of Nullable`, which Crystal does not understand. Not sure when they will support this. See this link [crystal-does-not-support-systemnullable](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9788f39c-2f3a-489d-8586-e7fc7c429e3b/crystal-does-not-support-systemnullable)